# Integrating javascript with computer sound input device

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, speaker

I am developing an app with javascript which records audio using html 5 audio context. I want to develop a feature which needs whether the current active sound device is connected microphone or default laptop/computer microphone and adjust its settings like decreasing its volume. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [MediaDevices.getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) API method. The user will be prompted for permission to use the audio input device. Browser support is currently limited to Chrome, Firefox and Opera,see http://caniuse.com/#search=MediaRecorder.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
.then(function (stream) {
  // the audio stream is available here
  recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  // listen to dataavailable, which gets triggered
  // when an audio blob is available
  recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', onRecordingReady);
});

function onRecordingReady(e) {
  // e.data contains a blob that represents the recording
}
```